# Default field value with springSecurityService

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm sure I've seen this before, but I can't find anything about it now.  When I attempt to do this:

```
class Foo {

    def springSecurityService
    User userInstance = springSecurityService.currentUser

}
```

I get the following error towards the end of compilation:

> Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object

Can I not set the default user with a service?

- Running Grails 2.2.0.
- `Foo` is a domain class.

**EDIT**

I tried the below solution with `javax.annotations.PostConstruct`, but the annotated method is never called. I don't think it's being called because I put a `println` statement in it, which doesn't get called. I'm instantiating my class with `new Foo()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

class Foo {

    def springSecurityService
    User userInstance

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        userInstance = springSecurityService.currentUser
    }
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're trying to set `userInstance` before `springSecurityService` has been dependency-injected.

I'm assuming `Foo` is a domain class, if it's a class in `src/groovy` then this approach won't work, because these classes are not subject to dependency-injection.

Comment: Yeah, it's a domain class. I was just coming to the conclusion that dependency injection hadn't happened yet and wasn't sure what the best workaround was. Thanks!

Comment: Huh. Well, I don't get the compile error, but `init()` is never called :|

Comment: @CharlesWood why exactly do you need to store the current user in a field anyway, given that you can always access it from `springSecurityService`?

Comment: Because `Foo` is being persisted and I would like the database to remember who the current user was for later reference, the same as any field in a domain class.